# Reading text file in html and parsing it to an array for pull down menu

Tags: html, text, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have an html code snippet below:

```
   <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100%><tr>
   <td width=40% align="right">Name :</td>
   <td align='left' nowrap>"
   <select style="width=250px;height:18px;margin-bottom:5px;" id="name">
      <option value=''>David</option>
      <option value=''>Erika</option>
      <option value=''>Stephanie</option>
      <option value=''>Steven</option>
      <option value=''>Angela</option>
    </select>
```

Now since the amount of names might get really large, I have a text file that just lists the names.  How can I get the html to read the text file so that I can have a pull down menu with the names in the text file based on the snippet of code above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your reasoning is for not wanting to put the names directly in the HTML file, but if you are just trying to avoid typing the `<option>` tags around each name, you could use a script to do so.

Change your `<select>` code to be just the list, for example:

```
<select style="width=250px;height:18px;margin-bottom:5px;" id="name">John
    Barry
    More
    Drew
    Brees
    David
    Erika
    Stephanie
    Johnny
    Angela
    Steven
</select>
```

Then add this script right before your `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
    var sel = document.getElementById("name");
    var names = sel.innerHTML.split("\n");
    var i = 0;
    sel.innerHTML = "";
    for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        sel.innerHTML += "<option value=''>" + names[i] + "</option>";
    }
</script>
```

I hope this helps.